# ionic2 - changing the color for loading screen

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

I am using `LoadingController` for many pages in my app. I want to do some customisation so that it works with the design and brand. I want to change:

1. backdrop color.
2. get rid of the white box that contain the text.
3. use my own spinner.

I find out the backdrop is in `ion-backdrop` and white box container is in `loading-wrapper`,`loading-ios`(if it is in iOS). 
So I add the code in `app.scss`:

```
.ion-backdrop{
  background: rgba(0,20,0,.5);
}
.loading-ios, .loading-wrapper{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

but nothing happen. How can I do that?

And how to change the spinner with our own graphic?

**Update 01:**
I found out there is a `cssClass` options for `create()` so I tried:

```
presentLoadingCustom() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    // showBackdrop: false,
    cssClass:`
    .custom-spinner-container{
      background:#445566;
    } 
    `,
    content: `
       <div class="custom-spinner-container">
        <div class="custom-spinner-box">loading somethung</div>
      </div>
      `,
    duration: 20000
  });

  loading.onDidDismiss(() => {
    console.log('Dismissed loading');
  });

  loading.present();
}
```

But I got error:

> Error in ./LoadingCmp class LoadingCmp_Host - inline template:0:0
>   caused by: The string contains invalid characters.

How to do the `css` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out:

You can override `ionic` variables of `theme/variables.scss`. In `theme/variables.scss`:

```
$backdrop-color:#002559;//<-- I add in this.
```

And it works. Go to [this link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) to check out all the variable that you want to change.